# Django - File Logging which owner

Tags: django, logging

I'm running on a production server with WSGI & Apache.
I'm configuring a **file logging** for my Django project like:

**settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        #...
        'logfile': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django/my_project.log'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        #...
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

How can I know which user should own the file `/var/log/django/my_project.log` ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply `chown <your_username>` the log file?

Comment: Because my_username is not the one who runs the Django server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may run the WSGI process as a specific user, e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess yourapplication user=user1 group=group1 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/yourapplication/yourapplication.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/yourapplication>
        WSGIProcessGroup yourapplication
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Ideally to the one who owns `/var/log/django`. (`stat /var/log/django --printf=%U`)

Comment: That is interesting. Will this user be the same that writes files in the media folder on user upload ?